# How to disable GUI in Ubuntu with exceptions

Tags: firefox, gui, raspberrypi, browser

I am working on a Raspberry pi based system which requires me to use only a web browser through a touch screen. I want to run everything as a startup script and disable all other GUI elements except the Firefox browser. Is it possible? And if so, how do I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide OS & release details (and if not using the default GUI, what DE you have installed)